I want to send parameters to a GraphQL query from my flutter application
I want to send parameters to a GraphQL query from my flutter application, but it doesn't work. I declared a variable and write to it when I select by which criteria I am going to sort the query.
Query in Flutter:
String getAllPlanner = '''
      query{
        allPlanners(orderby: \$orderby){
        code,
          error,
          list{
          id,
            service{
              id,
            }
            client{
              id,
            }
            startDate,
            endDate,
            status
          }
        }
      }
''';

Calling the query:
Query(
        options: QueryOptions(document: gql(getAllPlanner)),
        builder: (result, {fetchMore, refetch}) {
          if (result.isLoading) {
            return Container();
          }
          print(getAllPlanner.toString());
          print("Result getAllPlanner = " + result.data.toString());
          }
        return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                itemCount: listplanner.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Planner planner = extractRepositoryDataPlanner(
                    "",
                    listplanner[index],
                  );
                  return PlannerItem(
                    planner: planner,
                    index: index,
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        });

Seleccting criteria and saving in to a varible "orderby":
                    RadioListTile(
                      title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dateUpward),
                      value: sortingOptions.dateUpward,
                      groupValue: selectedSortingOptions,
                      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        selectedSortingOptions = sortingOptions.dateUpward;
                        orderby = "startDate";
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }),
                    ),
                    RadioListTile(
                      title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dateFalling),
                      value: sortingOptions.dateFalling,
                      groupValue: selectedSortingOptions,
                      onChanged: (value){
                          orderby = "-startDate";
                          print(orderby);
                          selectedSortingOptions = sortingOptions.dateFalling;
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),

Testing query:

